# Is it possible that an iOS application can have more than one window?

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I have been asked this question many times in the interview searched every where didn't get any proper answer.So finally posting this question here.

Comment: Check this out! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow

Comment: yes, it can have more than one window; but one could be the _key_ only at the same time. what is your plan with using multiple windows?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may go through this.

Yes, you can have multiple windows. A key window is the one that receives the user input.

Starting with Rob's answer I played around a bit and would like to write down some notes for others trying to get information on this topic:

1. It is not a problem at all to add another `UIWindow`. Just create one
   and `makeKeyAndVisible`. Done.
2. Remove it by making another window
   visible, then release the one you don't need anymore.
3. The window that is "key" receives all the keyboard input.
4. `UIWindow` covers everything, even modals, popovers, etc. Brilliant!
5. `UIWindow` is always in portrait implicitly. It does not rotate.
6. You'll have to add a controller to the new window's root controller and let that handle rotation.
7. (Just like the main window) The window's level determines
   how "high" it gets displayed. Set it to UIWindowLevelStatusBar to have it cover everything.
8. Set its hidden property to NO. A 2nd
   `UIWindow` can be used to bring views on the screen that float on top of everything. Without creating a dummy controller just to embed that in a UIPopoverController.
9. It can be especially useful for iPhone where there is no popover controller but where you might want to mimic something like it.
10. And yes, it solved, of course, my problem: if
    the app resigns activation, add a cover window over whatever is
    currently shown to prevent iOS from taking a screenshot of your
    app's current content.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Generally one application require only 1 UIWindow, but still there may be some scenarios where you need to use multiple UIWindow in one application.

For example, you wish to show a view on the top of system AlertViews, or can the default Keyboard.

UIWindows are the special UIViews, for which their display order is controlled by .windowLevel property.

You don't need to add a new UIWindow as a subview of any of view. You can simply create a new UIWindow and call either window setHidden:NO or window makeKeyAndVisible depend on the level, you have given to it.

There are three default window enum levels defined:

- `UIWindowLevelNormal`
- `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`
- `UIWindowLevelAlert`

Answer (score -1):

Of course it can have multiple windows. Just, only one to be displayed at a time, that's the `keyWindow`. You can have multiple windows stored in array or whatsoever, and make them `keyWindow` when you want to display them.

And, yeah, read the documentation @Mannopson suggested, it's very useful.

Comment: You can have as many UIWindows visible at a given time as you want, not one. `keywindow` is the one that receives non touch events, e.g. keyboard.